Can i use parenthesis or not with IF in Snowflake?
So, im trying to figure this out, can u use:
IF ( <condition> ) THEN
But, can this be like this too?
IF <condition> THEN
I was trying to find info about this on the documentation, but i dont see it anywhere.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/if
The only place, where i see this, is here
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-IF-THEN-ELSE-statement-in-Snowflake-scripting
Im going to add the section with the problem, but im not trying to solve the problem in this post, im asking for the IF and ().
        IF :DATE_FROM IS NULL THEN
            CASE period_value
                WHEN 'daily' THEN
                    calculated_date_from := DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE());
                    calculated_date_to := calculated_date_from;
                WHEN 'weekly' THEN
                    calculated_date_from := DATEADD(WEEK, -1, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'WEEK'));
                    calculated_date_to := DATEADD(DAY, 6, calculated_date_from);
                WHEN 'monthly' THEN
                    calculated_date_from := DATEADD(MONTH, -1, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'MONTH'));
                    calculated_date_to := LAST_DAY(calculated_date_from);
                ELSE
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unsupported periodicity: %', period_row.period_value;
            END CASE;
        ELSE
            calculated_date_from := :DATE_FROM;
            calculated_date_to := :DATE_TO;
        END IF;


Hi - so what happened when you tried both ways?

I have an error, but is not related to syntax or smt and a guy told me that parenthesis are not allowed, linking this post https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/1cry73o/if_statement_is_giving_me_a_headache/
Thats why im trying to find confirmation. If A people says i can, and B people says i cant, where can i find more info about it ?

I’m still not clear what’s stopping you trying this with/without parentheses and therefore getting the definitive answer for yourself?

Also the documentation for SQL Scripting IF statements (here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch#if-statements) seems to be clear about what the syntax is

@NickW again, i just told you, i have an issue, but people are telling me that there is a problem with the IF. What im trying to get, its to confirm which is the true. Ive tried both ways, but people keep telling me that i MUST use parenthesis.

I shared you the docs, and there is nothing that says "its allowed" or "isnt allowed", its on the post.

The documentation states “The syntax for the IF statement is:
IF () THEN … “ - which clearly has parentheses

Yes, but it works without it. So idk which one is true, thats why im asking, is clearly in the post what my intentions are.
